# Content Binding in AvalonDock 2.0

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock

I'm trying to assign some of my old AvalonDock concepts to AD 2.0. I noticed that `DocumentContent` is replaced by `LayoutDocument`. By accessing the `LayoutDocumentPane` forms can be added easily by `.Children.add()`. However, the creation of new forms is threaded in my application (`InitializeComponents` takes a while) and the addition of documents to the docking system is executed by an invoke. This leads to an InvalidOperation and I guess it cannot be fixed because it's WPF. I hope to handle this issue by using Bindings. Starting from my AD1 code, I realized that all properties are in the `Content` object. Adding the `Content.` to the binding sources will make my document header look like definied by the template. See my XAML here:

```
<AD:DockingManager Name="dockManager" DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}" >
   <AD:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Content.IconSource}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content.Title}" />
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </AD:DockingManager.DocumentHeaderTemplate>
   <AD:LayoutRoot PropertyChanged="OnLayoutRootPropertyChanged">
        <AD:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <AD:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                <AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
             </AD:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
             <AD:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="300">
                <AD:LayoutAnchorablePane x:Name="rightPanel">
                </AD:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            </AD:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
       </AD:LayoutPanel>
   </AD:LayoutRoot>
</AD:DockingManager>
```

Documents definition:

```
public ObservableCollection<LayoutDocument> Documents { get; private set; }
```

If I now add some new form to `Documents` the header is right but the window content is not shown. Instead of this the class name of the window is printed. I think it's a similar to the header and some reference to the `.Content` is missing and I see some `.ToString()` result of the object on higher level. How to determine that the `Content` is assigned to the window content?

If there is some fallacy in my approach tell me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need add some `resources` to your `DockingManager` to show up your View corresponding to `ViewModel Instance`,

```
<AD:DockingManager.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel1}">// your ViewModel Name comes here.
                <Views:View1 DataContext="{Binding}" /> // your View Comes here. DataContext is not required if you specify it on the UserControl.      
  </DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:ViewModel2}">
                <Views:View2 DataContext="{Binding}" />       
  </DataTemplate>
</AD:DockingManager.Resources>
```

And your `Documents collection` should have the `ViewModel` Instance

**EDIT** based on the comments below,

```
 <AD:DockingManager>
     <AD:LayoutRoot>
        <AD:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <AD:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
                       <!--Your View/UserControl goes here-->
                    </AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
                    <AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
                       <!--Your View/UserControl goes here-->
                    </AD:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </AD:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
             </AD:LayoutPanel>
        </AD:LayoutRoot>
  </AD:DockingManager>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain or show an example what is `ViewModels:AdvancedSearchViewModel` and `Views` here? (I'm relatively new to WPF)

Comment: How does that work if `LayoutDocument` has no `DataContext` ?

Comment: ok you don't want to add `DataContext` if its not available. I am guessing you are having `UserControls` as different Views for your documents and each `UserControl` is associated with a `ViewModel`.  if that is the case then create your `ViewModel` instance and add to your `Documents` collection will work.

Comment: @NilsKeller added some comments in the answer have a look.

Comment: Yes, as different UserControls I use OpenTK (WinForms OpenGL Control) in a `WindowsFormsHost`. I'm not sure how to define the View and ViewModel.

Comment: `View` is your `UserControl` and `ViewModel` is what your `UserControl bindings`  are you following MVVM ?

Comment: In `AvalonDock` documents are binded using `DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"` it supporting MVVM and the list contains ViewModel instances, if you are not following MVVM then you can remove `DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}"` and add the Documents static. I will edit my answer so that you can understand better.

Comment: I see. So I guess MVVM will not work for me since I want to add completely different and complex windows. The problem is still that static document adding is not working by Invoke. I'll look forward to some asynchronious threading solutions. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Checked as answer since the other way seems not feasable.